# nodejs function call thread handling :: there has to be other threads

Tags: multithreading, node.js

I have one question 
Since nodejs is single threaded model and put the function call in stack to be called asynchronously. That would help main thread not getting blocked.. Now my question is; don't we have another thread which is taking care of handling the stacked function calls.. Is that right understanding

Thanks

Comment: what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: Sorry this was wrong comments... It was for other question which I posted...

Comment: Sorry the comment was added to wrong question.. I would delete the comment.. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: node.js uses a single thread because it's javascript. But it's obvious that internally it has a multithread architecture. It's impossible to do a I/O access without blocking using only a single thread... Common sense, please. http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Comment: Thanks a lot... That is where I was heading to.. So nodejs have one thread with takes care of requests and other threadS which takes care of I/O operations... Now my question is typical web servers like Apache spawn threads as and when requests come.. Now what is the difference between the worker threads used by nodejs for I/O and Apache webserver's thread spawned as and when request come... I assume the worked threads are better performing? what exactly is the diffference between those two